# Autofill form data after login

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which user can fill if he is not logged in. But the form cannot be submitted unless he is logs in. If the user is not logged in , he is redirected to the login form . But the issue is when the person logs in and clicks on the same form the data he filled previously is lost. There are 20 fields which he has to fill again. 
What should I use to maintain the data ? should i save in the database, should i use cookies , session ?? How is it done usually ??

And what if the user fills the form and doesn not login ? The other user who uses the system will see the previous data in the form. How is this handled.

Please help

Comment: you can use cookie and set time so after some time destrory cookie

Comment: but is not it better to limit the page only logged in users?

Comment: @TheDude it's definitely to only show the form to logged in users

Comment: if user is new to the site he would not give his details and register unless he knows the website

Comment: for example with [Ultimate Member](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) plug-in you can restrict only the content of a page/post to a specific role members ([doc](http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/226-restrict-content-on-a-page-post-to-specific-users-community-role))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use sessions. Just populate each session variable from `$_POST`and echo to correct input field if its set:

```
<?php

session_start();

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$sesFname = $_SESSION['firstname'] = $fname;

?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php 

        if (isset($sesFname)){
        echo $sesFname;
        }

?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then `session_unset()` to free resource when it's not needed.

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php